# Unable to search Unicode data in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, unicode

I have a table orders where in i have data stored in Unicode format. The other data is in unicode format i.e Hindi.

Screenshot of the table structure is enclosed herewith.
[Table Data Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nq4km.png)
The data stored in the table can be viewed from this picture. 
[Table Data View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WxB6I.png)

The sql dump for the table is given below:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `orders` (
    `sno` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
    `CaseNO` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `Court` varchar(255) NOT NULL, 
    `Yr` varchar(4) NOT NULL,
    `CaseType` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    `Dt_Disposal` varchar(10) NOT NULL, 
    `App_Name` longtext NOT NULL, 
    `App_F_Name` longtext NOT NULL, 
    `Res_Name` text NOT NULL, 
    `Res_F_Name` text NOT NULL, 
    `Pet_Cou_Name` varchar(255) NOT NULL, 
    `Res_Cou_Name` varchar(255) NOT NULL, 
    `Pro_Off_Name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `District` varchar(255) NOT NULL, 
    `Division` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `Tehsil` varchar(255) NOT NULL, 
    `Path` longtext NOT NULL, 
    `UName` varchar(255) NOT NULL, 
    `CCY` varchar(255) NOT NULL, 
    `Page_Cnt` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `Dis_year` varchar(4) NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (`sno`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

--

### -- Dumping data for table `orders_bkp`

```
INSERT INTO `orders` (`sno`, `CaseNO`, `Court`, `Yr`, `CaseType`, `Dt_Disposal`, `App_Name`, `App_F_Name`, `Res_Name`, `Res_F_Name`, `Pet_Cou_Name`, `Res_Cou_Name`, `Pro_Off_Name`, `District`, `Division`, `Tehsil`, `Path`, `UName`, `CCY`, `Page_Cnt`, `Dis_year`)
    VALUES
    ('1', '127', 'PBR', '76', 'अपील', '13/01/86', 'सनमान सिंह', 'मुंशीलाल', 'मध्‍य प्रदेश शासन', '', 'अरूण मिश्रा', 'आर०एस० बाजपेई', 'सुरेन्‍द्र नाथ', 'विदिशा', 'भोपाल संभाग', 'विदिशा', 'A:\\Gwalior\\Appeal_complete\\1986\\Jan\\1000001.tif', 'Akash:1/2/2018 11:47:42 AM', '127-PBR/76', 8, '1986'),
    ('10', '39', 'III', '85', 'अपील', '17/01/86', 'अब्‍बास अहमद', 'अब्‍दुल बहबल', 'जिला सहकारी केन्‍द्रीय बैंक मर्यादित', '', 'आर०के० मेहता', 'वी०एम० निमगॉंवकर', 'सुरेन्‍द्र नाथ', 'उज्जैन', 'उज्जैन संभाग', 'उज्जैन', 'A:\\Gwalior\\Appeal_complete\\1986\\Jan\\1000083.tif', 'Akash:3/14/2011 12:25:18 AM', '39-III/85', 4, '1986'),
    ('19', '47', 'III', '85', 'अपील', '29/01/86', 'मेसर्स जयन्‍तीलाल एण्‍ड क०', '', 'विक्रय कर आयुक्‍त म०प्र०', '', 'जी०एल० यदु', 'आर०एन० झरिया', 'सुरेन्‍द्र नाथ', '', '', '', 'A:\\Gwalior\\Appeal_complete\\1986\\Jan\\1000087.tif', 'Akash:1/3/2018 10:50:50 AM', '47-III/85', 3, '1986'),('2', '8', 'I', '85', 'अपील', '31/01/86', 'नटवर लाल', '', 'विक्रय कर आयुक्‍त म०प्र०', '', '', 'ए०सी० तिवारी', 'एम०बी०आर०', 'भोपाल', 'भोपाल संभाग', '', 'A:\\Gwalior\\Appeal_complete\\1986\\Jan\\1000050.tif', 'Akash:1/2/2018 3:37:41 PM', '8-I/85', 5, '1986'),('2', '183', 'I', '83', 'अपील', '16/01/86', 'मेसर्स संजीव कुमार विकास कुमार', '', 'विक्रय कर आयुक्‍त म०प्र०', '', 'रामचरण लाल गुप्‍ता', 'ए०सी० तिवारी', 'स०च० जैन', 'भिण्ड', 'चम्बल संभाग', 'गोहद', 'A:\\Gwalior\\Appeal_complete\\1986\\Jan\\1000009.tif', 'Akash:1/2/2018 11:53:31 AM', '183-I/83', 9, '1986'),('20', '48', 'III', '85', 'अपील', '20/01/86', 'जिला सहकारी केन्‍द्रीय बैंक मर्यादित', '', 'ब्रजनंदन खरे', '', 'एस०के० जैन', 'एस०के० अवस्‍थी', 'सुरेन्‍द्र नाथ', 'टीकमगढ़', 'सागर संभाग', 'टीकमगढ़', 'A:\\Gwalior\\Appeal_complete\\1986\\Jan\\1000090.tif', 'Akash:1/3/2018 11:01:45 AM', '48-III/85', 2, '1986'),('21', '49', 'III', '85', 'अपील', '29/01/86', 'मेसर्स एस०के० ट्रेडिंग क०', '', 'विक्रय कर आयुक्‍त म०प्र०', '', 'के०सी० देशलेहरा', 'आर०एन० झरिया', 'सुरेन्‍द्र नाथ', '', '', '', 'A:\\Gwalior\\Appeal_complete\\1986\\Jan\\1000092.tif', 'Akash:1/3/2018 11:10:39 AM', '49-III/85', 4, '1986'),('22', '50', 'III', '85', 'अपील', '29/01/86', 'मेसर्स अलाइड स्‍टील मर्यादित', '', 'विक्रय कर आयुक्‍त म०प्र०', '', 'एल०के० अहलूवालिया', 'आर०एन० झरिया', 'सुरेन्‍द्र नाथ', '', '', '', 'A:\\Gwalior\\Appeal_complete\\1986\\Jan\\1000096.tif', 'Akash:1/3/2018 11:26:05 AM', '50-III/85', 4, '1986'),('23', '54', 'III', '85', 'अपील', '20/01/86', 'नाथूराम यादव', 'रामदास यादव', 'वृहत्‍ताकार सहकारी समिति मर्यादित ~सहायक पंजीयक, सहकारी समितियां ~छिद्दूलाल', 'कामता प्रसाद', 'एस०के० अवस्‍थी', 'एस०के० वाजपेई', 'सुरेन्‍द्र नाथ', 'टीकमगढ़', 'सागर संभाग', 'टीकमगढ़', 'A:\\Gwalior\\Appeal_complete\\1986\\Jan\\1000100.tif', 'Akash:1/3/2018 11:39:17 AM', '54-III/85', 3, '1986'),('24', '58', 'III', '85', 'अपील', '24/01/86', 'सागर जिला सहकारी भूमि विकास बैंक मर्यादित', '', 'सागर सहकारी कृषक एवं विपणन संस्‍था मर्या०', '', 'एन०डी० सिंघल', '', 'सुरेन्‍द्र नाथ', 'सागर', 'सागर संभाग', 'सागर', 'A:\\Gwalior\\Appeal_complete\\1986\\Jan\\1000103.tif', 'Akash:1/3/2018 11:56:45 AM', '58-III/85', 2, '1986');
```

**The code for the search parameters is given below**

```
  <form action="test2.php" method="post" name="form1">
      <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2">
        <tr>
          <td colspan="3" align="center" bgcolor="#000000" class="title3">Please select the search criteria</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="45%" align="right" class="formtext">Case No</td>
          <td width="2%" align="center"><strong class="formtext">:</strong></td>
          <td width="53%"><input type="text" name="CaseNO" id="CaseNO">
            <span class="text10pt">

            </span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr align="right" class="formtext">
          <td>Case Year</td>
          <td align="center"><strong>:</strong></td>
          <td align="left"><label>
            <input type="text" name="Yr" id="Yr">
          </label></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="formtext">
          <td align="right">Case Type</td>
          <td align="center"><strong class="formtext">:</strong></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="CaseType" id="CaseType"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="formtext">
          <td align="right">Court</td>
          <td align="center">:</td>
          <td><input type="text" name="Court" id="Court"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="formtext">
          <td align="right">Date of Disposal</td>
          <td align="center"><strong class="formtext">:</strong></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="Dt_Disposal" id="Dt_Disposal"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="right" class="formtext">Applicant Name</td>
          <td align="center"><strong class="formtext">:</strong></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="App_Name" id="App_Name"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="right" class="formtext">Respondent Name</td>
          <td align="center"><strong class="formtext">:</strong></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="Res_Name" id="Res_Name"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="right"><span class="formtext">Petitioner Counsel  Name</span></td>
          <td align="center"><strong class="formtext">:</strong></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="Pet_Cou_Name" id="Pet_Cou_Name"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="right"><span class="formtext">Respondent Counsel  Name</span></td>
          <td align="center"><strong class="formtext">:</strong></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="Res_Cou_Name" id="Res_Cou_Name"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="right"><span class="formtext">District</span></td>
          <td align="center"><strong class="formtext">:</strong></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="District" id="District"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="right"><span class="formtext">Proceeding Officer Name</span></td>
          <td align="center"><strong class="formtext">:</strong></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="Pro_Off_Name" id="Pro_Off_Name"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="right"><span class="formtext">Divison</span></td>
          <td align="center"><strong class="formtext">:</strong></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="Division" id="Division"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="right"><span class="formtext">Tehsil</span></td>
          <td align="center"><strong class="formtext">:</strong></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="Tehsil" id="Tehsil"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td><input name="id_sflag" type="hidden" id="id_sflag" value="1"></td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="right"><label>
            <input type="submit" name="button5" id="button7" value="Submit">
          </label></td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td><input type="reset" name="button5" id="button8" value="Reset"></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </form>
```

My problem is that whenever i query english text from the table I get the results. But when i query the unicode data i do not get the results. The query works perfectly fine in phpmyadmin.

Sample of the query is given below

```
 SELECT * from orders WHERE App_Name LIKE '%काशी%';
```

**This query works perfectly fine when run in phpmyadmin where i get the results. But it does returns 0 records when run through a Php Page.**

My code is constructing a dynamic query passed on from previous page which can have 13 search parameters.The code is given below

```
 $mysqli_link= new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "revenue");
 mysqli_set_charset( $mysqli_link, 'utf8');
 if($_POST['id_sflag']=='1') 
 {
 // define the list of fields
 $fields = array('CaseNO', 'Yr', 'CaseType', 'Court', 'Dt_Disposal', 'App_Name', 'Res_Name', 'Pet_Cou_Name', 'Res_Cou_Name', 'District', 'Pro_Off_Name', 'Division', 'Tehsil');
$conditions = array();
 }

 // builds the query
 $query = "SELECT * from orders";

 // loop through the defined fields
 foreach($fields as $field){
// if the field is set and not empty
if(isset($_POST[$field]) && !empty($_POST[$field])) {
    // create a new condition while escaping the value inputed by the user (SQL Injection)
    $conditions[] = "$field LIKE '%" . mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli_link, $_POST[$field]) . "%'";
    }
}
 // if there are conditions defined
 if(count($conditions) > 0) {
// append the conditions
$query .= " WHERE " . implode (' AND ', $conditions); // you can change to 'OR', but I suggest to apply the filters cumulative
 }

 echo "$query<br>";

 $result = mysqli_query($mysqli_link, $query);
 //var_dump($result);
 $num_rows=mysqli_num_rows($result);
 mysqli_close($mysqli_link);
```

The retrieval code is :

```
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
                 {
                    $dis=$row['District'];
                    $div=$row['Division'];
                    $teh=$row['Tehsil'];
                    $cnt1=$row['Page_Cnt'];
                    $dyear=$row['Dis_year'];
                    $filen=$row['CCY'];
                    $newfile=$string = str_replace("/","_",$filen);
                    $newfile1="judgements/"."$dyear"."/"."$newfile".".pdf";
                    $Appname=$row['App_Name'];
                    $resname=$row['Res_Name'];
                    $disposal=$row['Dt_Disposal'];
                    $officer=$row['Pro_Off_Name'];
                    $pcnt=$row['Page_Cnt'];
                    printf("
                  <tr> 
                    <td class=\"sub6\">%s</td>
                    <td class=\"sub6\">%s</td>
                    <td class=\"sub6\">%s</td>
                    <td class=\"sub6\">%s</td>
                    <td class=\"sub6\">%s</td>
                    <td class=\"sub6\">%s</td>
                    <td class=\"sub6\">%s / %s  / %s</td>
                    <td class=\"sub6\">%s</td>
                    <td class=\"sub6\"><a href=\"%s\">View Order</a></td>
                      </tr>\n",$i,$filen,$Appname,$resname,$disposal,$officer,$dis,$div,$teh,$pcnt,$newfile1);
                $tot=$tot+$cnt1;  
              $i=$i+1;
              }
```

There is no problem is the query but somehow it does not fetch the records for the unicode data stored in the database.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: The query which i have pasted here is the one which has been constructed. Observe the echo $query tag. I have echoed the query to check it and have pasted it here.

Comment: You must create a minimal complete verifiable example. A code that creates a table, inserts a value and then tries to select it back - so anyone could run it and confirm your problem

Comment: where i can send the sample code to you. It will have the complete code, the table structure and data along with the pages.

Comment: It should be a Minimal example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: The code example can be downloaded by clicking this link
http://apply-online.co.in/minimal_example.rar

You can recreate the scenario. Whenever you search English parameters the query executes. It does not work whenever the unicode field is searched.

Comment: Not meant to offend you. I am a newbee to this site. Could not find a way to upload it. Now I have edited the entire question with all relevant data structure and dumps, the search form and the result page.

Requesting your help.

Answer (score 0):

I have found out the answer. The answer was not given on this site though.

I was missing out the following statement on both the form page and the result page

```
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
```

I added this line and it worked like a charm.

Comment: Current browsers _usually_ default to that.

Comment: Yes they do. Infact my code already had this 
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"><style type="text/css"> But still it was not working. Added the above line and it worked.

Comment: Perhaps the `<form...>` needed a `charset=UTF-8` attribute:  `<form accept-charset="UTF-8">`, as mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf-8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored